# How do I expand the .SDE file specified in my current workspace?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1

I'm storing my database connection in a .SDE file. When I output my feature class names in that database connection, I get the full path to the .SDE file. I want the details, like instance, for the database stored in the .SDE file. How do I expand (maybe not the right term) the .SDE file to expose the actual database details?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Describe](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018v00000066000000) function to get extended information about various objects. See [Workspace properties](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Workspace_properties/018v0000002v000000/), which also includes a good code sample that does pretty much exactly what you're after.